# Dynamic rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet that I read using python. I was looking for a way in which I could query the first column of the spreadsheet and assign every cell from that column to a variable. The number of cells in the column that have data can change tomorrow for ex.
Excel Spreadsheet:

```
Names
Mike
Adam
Mitchell
```

Desired output: Name1=Mike; Name2= Adam;Name3=Mitchell. If tomorrow there is no Mitchell in the list or if there is an additional name I would either have 3 Name variable or respectively 4.
My try so far was:

```
for i in db.index:
if i == 1:
    Name1 = db.ix[0]['Names']
else:
    if i==2:
        Name2 = db.ix[1]['Names']
    else:
        if i==3:
            Name3 = db.ix[2]['Names']
        else:
            Name4 = db.ix[3]['Names']
```

Thanks and apologies for any mystakes

Comment: Why explicit variables like `Name1` and `Name2`? Why not an array like `Names` that you can index with `Names[0]` and `Names[1]`? The hard-coded variables may back you into a corner later on.

Comment: How would that look in my case Chris(array with index). I need the variable Name1, Name2 etc later one as I use them to sort some other data.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this in case anyone else has the same issue. I am using 2 lists and concatenate them into a dictionary.

```
names= db['Names'].tolist()
lst = []
for i in range(db.index):
    lst.append(i)
lst=['Name'+str(x)for x in lst]
dictionary = dict(zip(lst, names))
```